# REST api authentication mechanism

Tags: web-services, security, rest, restful-authentication

I'm using a custom protocol to secure my REST API - 
Hash a bunch of unique data together (including the user's token) and sending it as an Authorization header (very similar to [AWS rest api](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html)).

Currently, I'm making the user send it's un\pw in order to get a token for all future calls:

```
POST http://xxxx/token
Body: {"username" : "Bob", "password":"foo"}
```

My question is how should I secure the initial login call that produces the user's token? Is the current situation good enough?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution looks like a call to a j_security_servlet having username and password in the POST's body.
You can find more about the servlet here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/Security5.html

You might want to choose a TLS secured connection to encrypt your username/password that you send over.
But you might want to think about HTTP Basic Authentication in combination with TLS or some other proven technologies instead of designing your own one.

Btw. my answer is use SSL/TLS.

Answer (score 0):

You might as well use OAuth2 since that is essentially what you are implementing. See "4.3. Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant": https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3

In OAuth2 the request goes like this (example from the RFC):

```
 POST /token HTTP/1.1
 Host: server.example.com
 Authorization: Basic czZCaGRSa3F0MzpnWDFmQmF0M2JW
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

 grant_type=password&username=johndoe&password=A3ddj3w
```

The "Authorization" header use used to authorize the client application, the username/password in the body is your user's credentials.

Here is the corresponding response:

```
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
 Cache-Control: no-store
 Pragma: no-cache

 {
   "access_token":"2YotnFZFEjr1zCsicMWpAA",
   "token_type":"example",
   "expires_in":3600,
   "refresh_token":"tGzv3JOkF0XG5Qx2TlKWIA",
   "example_parameter":"example_value"
 }
```

OAuth2 requires TLS/SSL for security (like brazo also answers).